# Clocking into separate file

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

Is it possible to set up an agenda file in org-mode, so that the clocking information is saved at a different location?

At work we have a team-global and version-controlled file with a section hierarchy which I would like to use as an agenda file to do my clocking.  But because this file is used by several people and because it might change (someone might add a new section), logging the clocking times into this file is not really an option.

So, can I tell org-mode to save the logged clocking times at a different location?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Not without significant code changes.

The 'org-clock-in' function has a hook called 'org-clock-in-prepare-hook' which could potentially duplicate the logging (although it wouldn't be trivial to make it happen.

It also has a hook which is run at the end of execution.  Neither of them trivially allow you to change the buffer used for logging.

Comment: Good to know.  I have a workflow now with git and manual merging if necessary, let's see how this turns out.